# Git log reading (commit Id list)

Tags: git, git-log

I wanted to take a list of commit Ids but I managed to get Ids + descriptions
How do I extract the Guid list ( basically remove the text)
I am new to PowerShell,  if someone can guide much appreciated

> `$ git log --pretty=oneline`
>
> ```
> 3396763626316124388f76be662bd941df591118 Add twitter 
> c73bbc98b5f55e5a4dbfee8e0297e4e1652a0687 add facebook
> ```

expected result

> ```
>    3396763626316124388f76be662bd941df591118
>    c73bbc98b5f55e5a4dbfee8e0297e4e1652a0687
> ```

Comment: (I replaced the `powershell` tags with `git-log` since the type of terminal is irrelevant to the question. Would be the exact same in bash context.)

Answer (score 2):

You could add to your log command the [format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emHem) `--pretty=format:"%H"`, but

```
git rev-list
```

... without any option does exactly what you wanted : explore all the commits it can find by ancestry, like `git log` does, but only outputs the long hashes. It's the plumbing counterpart to `git log`.

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))